# ReflectionProbe.RenderProbe() not working on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, reflection

In my project I have a curved reflective wall that is generated when the scene loads.
During the generation, I create ReflectionProbes at intervals along the wall. I then call .RenderProbe() on each in turn and then wait for the job to complete on all of them before starting the scene (switching cameras on, allowing the player and NPC's to move etc.)
This all works well in the editor but when I build for Android the call to RenderProbe() does exactly nothing.
Calls to isFinishedRendering() never return true.

My guess is that I'm missing a setting somewhere but so far I haven't found it.

Any suggestions about where to look or things I should check are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I spent about 3 hours on this yesterday and couldn't find any solution.
This morning, I posted this while eating breakfast.

I had become so convinced that I wouldn't find a solution that I was going to try to work round it by creating the curved wall in an editor script and baking the ReflectionProbes in advance.
(Much more complicated than I have made it sound because I wouldn't have access to the runtime interface of an imported asset and would instead be getting the data from analysing a mesh.)

Five minutes later, I have solved the problem.
Project Settings -> Quality -> Rendering -> Realtime Reflection Probes. Tick.

I swear it wasn't there yesterday or if it was it was already selected.
Anyway, call me a moron.
I'll leave this here for anyone else as stupid as me.